# Hide a specific node in a JSTree

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jstree, each

I have a standard jstree with a list of folder objects. The user is able to do a basic search for the name of a folder, and I want to hide all folders that do not match the search. Everything works fine up until the part where I need to actually hide the nodes that do not match.

```
//Iterate through all elements of the tree.
var xmlString = $("#standardTree").jstree("get_xml");
var xmlDOM = $.parseXML(xmlString);
var items = $(xmlDOM).find("root item");

$.each(items, function (key, item) {
     //If a node's text doesn't match the search, hide that node.
     if ($(item).text() != result.searchString) {

          //**Not sure what to do here, this doesn't work.**
          $(item).hide();
     }
});
```

Comment: use $(this).hide instead.

Comment: I may be wrong, but isn't $(this).hide() the exact same thing as $(item).hide() in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my solution.

By trying to use  $(item).hide(), I was trying to hide the object itself. I had to get the li element first, and then I was able to hide it without any problems.

```
$.each(items, function (key, item) {
    var treeNode = document.getElementById($(item).attr("id"));

    if ($(item).text() != result.searchString) {
        $(treeNode).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me

```
var isFiltered  = false;
function filter() {
    isFiltered = !isFiltered;       
    var filterText = document.getElementById("newParent").value;
    var $tree = $('#jstree');
    $($tree.jstree().get_json($tree, {
          flat: true
        }))
        .each(function(index, value) {
          var node = $("#jstree").jstree().get_node(this.id);         
          if (isFiltered && !node.text.includes(filterText))
            $("#jstree").jstree(true).hide_node(node);
        else
            $("#jstree").jstree(true).show_node(node);

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since jstree 3.2.0 it is also possible to use [hide_node](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=hide_node(obj)) to hide nodes. This means the node will still be hidden after a redraw.

```
$("#tree").jstree(true).hide_node(treeNode);
```